# NodeJs : How to send very large data from server to client

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am using Express Framework. I am trying to send very large data from server. The Client receives 200 OK status but no data. Also it gives error ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH even though I am sending the content-length Header from server. The content-length of my response is 2102619.

This is the code I used to send response:

```
var rowNew = JSON.stringify(row); 
res.set({ 'Content-Length': rowNew.length }); 
return res.status(200).send(row);
```

Also tried increasing the time limit to a very large:

```
server.timeout = 300000;
```

Comment: How are you sending it? What's the source of the data?

Comment: source code please

Comment: This is the code I used to send response :
var rowNew = JSON.stringify(row);
res.set({ 'Content-Length': rowNew.length });
return res.status(200).send(row);

Also tried increasing the time limit to a very large:
server.timeout = 300000;

Comment: you should check the request headers `Content-Type` that should be same as your response data type.

Comment: The Content-Type is same as my response data type

Comment: Note that the code is sending back `row` where `rowNew` is intended.

Comment: Note that the content length header specifies the size in bytes, while the length specifies the length inUTF 16 characters

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem requires some read, here's the solution

[Link to the solution](https://codingsans.com/blog/file-stream-nodejs)

One thing you probably haven’t taken full advantage of before is that webserver’s http response is a stream by default.

They just make it easier for you to pass in synchron data, which is parsed to chunks under the hood and sent as HTTP packages.

We are talking about huge files here; naturally, we don’t want them to be stored in any memory, at least not the whole blob. The excellent solution for this dilemma is a stream.

We create a readstream with the help of the built-in node package ‘fs,’ then pass it to the stream compatible response.send parameter.

```
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('example.png');
return response.headers({
  'Content-Type': 'image/png',
  'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="example.png"',
}).send(readStream);
```

I used Fastify webserver here, but it should work similarly with Koa or Express.

There are two more configurations here: naming the header ‘Content-Type’ and ‘Content-Disposition.’

The first one indicates the type of blob we are sending chunk-by-chunk, so the frontend will automatically give the extension to it.

The latter tells the browser that we are sending an attachment, not something renderable, like an HTML page or a script. This will trigger the browser’s download functionality, which is widely supported. The filename parameter is the download name of the content.

Here we are; we accomplished minimal memory stress, minimal coding, and minimal error opportunities.

One thing we haven’t mentioned yet is authentication.

For the fact, that the frontend won’t send an Ajax request, we can’t expect auth JWT header to be present on the request.

Here we will take the good old cookie auth approach. Cookies are set automatically on every request header that matches the criteria, based on the cookie options. More info about this in the frontend implementation part.

By default, cookies arrive as semicolon separated key-value pairs, in a single string. In order to ease out the parsing part, we will use Fastify’s Cookieparser plugin.

await fastifyServer.register(cookieParser);
Later in the handler method, we simply get the cookie that we are interested in and compare it to the expected value. Here I used only strings as auth-tokens; this should be replaced with some sort of hashing and comparing algorithm.

```
const cookies = request.cookies;
if (cookies['auth'] !== 'authenticated') {
   throw new APIError(400, 'Unauthorized');
}
```

That’s it. We have authentication on top of the file streaming endpoint, and everything is ready to be connected by the frontend.