# How to send huge datapool as response in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

In **node.js** application I take a huge datapool (200000 rows) from **MySQL** database.

```
await pool.query(query, binds, function (error, results) {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

I think the best way is sending data in chunks and streams instead of everything at once. I tried to use [JSONStream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream) package for this task but it's really confused. Can someone show me correct way to send huge datapool as response in node.js by this package?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/q/45779883/9020340

Comment: I already read article: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93 Unfortunately, there were more questions than answers.

Comment: According to your code its not seems you are sending data in streams. Consider this example to return data in streams http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-02-streams-basics.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
  // Make sure to set the correct content type
  res.set('content-type', 'application/json');

  // Stream the results
  pool.query(query, binds)
      .stream()
      .pipe(JSONStream.stringify())
      .pipe(res);
});
```

The trick is to call the `.stream()` method on the query, to stream the results, and pipe those results through `JSONStream` to stringify them into a JSON stream, which subsequently gets piped to the response.

More info on `mysql` streaming here:

- [Streaming query rows](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#streaming-query-rows)
- [Piping results with Streams](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#piping-results-with-streams)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! :)

Comment: can I ask you one more question? As a client I use `vue.js` application. I use `axios` package for requests to URLs. I think it's not good idea to use that package for this streaming API. What can you advice?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek what exactly do you want to do with the data? I'm not quite sure if there actually _are_ streaming clientside implementations (because, basically, unless you're downloading the data, you need to collect it all before you can use it).

Comment: the main task to show that huge data in webpage as fast as possible. `axios`  package wait all data, only then show it in webpage. Instead of that, I thought it would be better to show that data in streaming mode in webpage. For that's why I ask you what can we use as streaming in client side?

Comment: I don't think there's a (trivial) solution to ingesting streaming data clientside. Given the amount of data, have you considered implementation pagination?

Comment: In fact that data I want to show in map as polygons. So pagination is not solution in my case.